# Xserve G5 mysteriously powering down - why?

Tags: mac, shutdown, logging, xserve

We have an old Xserve dual G5 running Leopard client OS (don't ask).

Recently - after a few weeks of happy serving - it has started to shutdown overnight. The "Energy Saver" settings have been set to "never sleep" for everything.

Now the question is, is there a log somewhere I can check why this could be happening? No one in the office is owning up to doing it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you opened the Terminal and run the following command ***/usr/bin/syslog***?

You will be looking for a line similar to this:

> Sun Nov 1 22:55:51 Your-Xserve-G5 shutdown[303] : SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1257738951 243378

Look to see what is happening above that line. It should give you an indication as to what is happening.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Uh oh: "Tue Nov 10 10:12:23 Xserve kernel[0] <Debug>: ApplePMU::PMU forced shutdown, cause = -122"

Comment: Might be a problem with the power supply: http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=679299